How to disable Launch At Windows Startup in IMDisk?
I've been auto-mounting a RAMDisk with IMDisk for some time on Windows 10, and it works great but for the time being I don't need it running and I need some more system RAM.  I thought it would be trivial to just stop it from mounting at startup, but I can't seem to do so.  I can always unmount it manually, but I keep forgetting that it's still mounted and it's annoying.
I've disabled the Launch at Windows Startup option in the RAMDisk Configuration utility, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  Have hunted in Google for the answer to this but can't find anything.  How can I just stop it from auto-mounting with Windows?

In case anyone else runs into this, here is the answer.
Open the RAMDisk configuration tool, change nothing except to uncheck the "Mount at Startup" option, and click OK.  DO NOT click Exit.  You will be warned that you will lose the contents of the RAMDisk, and it will appear that a new disk is being created, but this is NOT actually the case!  Your disk will be unmounted, a new disk will appear to be getting created, but nothing will actually happen except that now your disk will not mount at startup.
This is unfortunately not a terribly obvious thing, when I tried it the first time it looked like it was just going to create a new drive which would be pointless, so I didn't go forward with the procedure.  Just know that this will in fact disable auto-mount at startup even though it may seem like it won't.
